# Parse only needed info from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Multiple xml files are dumped into a folder every morning containing one record each. Each of these files have nearly 300 nodes, but I only need to send off about 20 pieces of information. So for obvious reasons I would like to extract only the needed data rather than removing the not-needed data. I've been trying to do this with xslt, but can't quite get it right. I've tried so many different templates that I'm not going to post them here. Instead I'll just give an example of the source xml and what I need as an output xml.

Source.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NewDataSet xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Report>
        <Overview>
            <Agency>Agengcy1</Agency>
            <AgencyNumber>2346</AgencyNumber>
            <ReportDate>2017-07-24</ReportDate>
        </Overview>
        <Summary>
            <ReportNumber>17-092447</ReportNumber>
            <Boxes>2</Boxes>
            <Crates>1</Crates>
        </Summary>
        <Unit>
            <Order>
                <LastName>SMITH</LastName>
                <FirstName>JOHN</FirstName>
                <Address>123 MAIN</Address>
                <Floor>2</Floor>
                <State>IL</State>
                <City>CHICAGO</City>
                <Zip>60007</Zip>
            </Order>
        </Unit>
        <Unit>
            <Order>
                <LastName>SMITH</LastName>
                <FirstName>JANE</FirstName>
                <Address>123 MAIN</Address>
                <Floor>7</Floor>
                <State>IL</State>
                <City>CHICAGO</City>
                <Zip>60007</Zip>
            </Order>
        </Unit>
    </Report>
</NewDataSet>
```

Output.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Report xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Agency>Agengcy1</Agency>
    <ReportDate>2017-07-24</ReportDate>
    <ReportNumber>17-092447</ReportNumber>
        <Unit>
            <LastName>SMITH</LastName>
            <FirstName>JOHN</FirstName>
            <Floor>2</Floor>
        </Unit>
        <Unit>
            <LastName>SMITH</LastName>
            <FirstName>JANE</FirstName>
            <Floor>7</Floor>
        </Unit>
</Report>
```

What should my xslt look like to get the output.xml, including the indenting? Thank you in advance

**EDIT**
I tried the following but it leaves spaces in the output. Also, I stopped once I realized I would have to add nearly 300 xsl:template match="" statements.
This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AgencyNumber"/>
<xsl:template match="Boxes"/>
<xsl:template match="Crates"/>
<xsl:template match="Address"/>
<xsl:template match="State"/>
<xsl:template match="City"/>
<xsl:template match="Zip"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gets me this:

```
<Report>
    <Overview>
        <Agency>Agency1</Agency>

        <ReportDate>2017-07-24</ReportDate>
    </Overview>
    <Summary>
        <ReportNumber>17-092447</ReportNumber>


    <Unit>
        <Order>
            <LastName>SMITH</LastName>
            <FirstName>JOHN</FirstName>

            <Floor>2</Floor>



        </Order>
    </Unit>
</Report>
```

**2nd UPDATE**
I also used this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/NewDataSet/Report">
  <Report>
    <Agcy><xsl:value-of select="Overview/Agency" /></Agcy>
    <Date><xsl:value-of select="Overview/ReportDate" /></Date>
    <RprtNbr><xsl:value-of select="Summary/ReportNumber" /></RprtNbr>
        <Unit>
            <Last><xsl:value-of select="Unit/Order/LastName" /></Last>
            <First><xsl:value-of select="Unit/Order/FirstName" /></First>
            <Floor><xsl:value-of select="Unit/Order/Floor" /></Floor>
        </Unit>
  </Report>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it comes out like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Report><Agcy>Agengcy1</Agcy><Date>2017-07-24</Date><RprtNbr>17-092447</RprtNbr><Unit><Last>SMITH</Last><First>JOHN</First><Floor>2</Floor></Unit></Report>
```

Comment: Why not just load it into an XDocument, grab whatever is needed, and save it?

Comment: @Will  I'm new to the xml game and right now for various reasons I'm using Visual Studio's 'XML Task'. What is XDocument?

Comment: "*I've been trying to do this with xslt, but can't quite get it right.*" Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: You need to stop what you're doing and go read up on how to read and write XML using C#. Concentrate on examples that use "linq to xml".  Using xslt for this is going to be 10x harder.

Comment: Actually, doing this in XSLT is trivial.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yeah sorry, I'm not looking for anyone to do my work. I edited my post to include one example. I'll add another one of my attempts shortly.

Comment: I added another one of my attempts to the post, under 2nd Update.

Comment: Well, indenting aside, your 2nd attempt is incorrect because it only produces a single `Unit` node, regardless of how many there may be in the input XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing the pieces you don't want, try getting only the pieces you do want:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="Report">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Overview/Agency | Overview/ReportDate | Summary/ReportNumber"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Unit">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Order/LastName | Order/FirstName | Order/Floor"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or, if you prefer:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Overview">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Agency | ReportDate"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Summary">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ReportNumber"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Order">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="LastName | FirstName | Floor"/>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked! So the pipe character is what creates additional unit nodes? I appreciate the example! I was able to apply this to my real data and it came out just like I need it to. Now I can simply use the task inside a Visual Studio 'Foreach Loop Container' to cycle through all the files in the folder.

Comment: No, the pipe character is the union operator. What creates the additional `Unit` nodes is the `xsl:for-each` instruction in the first stylesheet, and the identity transform template in the second one.